# Issues with php connection to mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo

Hy everyone, I can't wrap my head around this. I'm trying to get some data from a table using PDO. this is my code:

```
//in db.php I have the connection:

$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'APL';
$dbuser = '';
$pass = ' ';

try{
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $dbuser, $pass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}


//in my file I have this:

$id = $_GET['id'];
$sel_sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =:id";
$stmt = $conn ->prepare($sel_sql);
$stmt -> bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt -> execute();
$result = $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The problem is that print_r($result) returns '1' (just the value 1, therefore I can't access any data stored in the table) as long as $_SESSION['user'] is set. 
The whole data-retrieving worked just fine if the $_SESSION['user'] is not set.

Can someone please explain why this is happening? (I'm fairly new to all this and I'm really trying to understand why some issues occur).

Thank you!

Comment: You don't use `$_SESSION['user']` anywhere in your code snippet so your error is probably somewhere else.

Comment: `fetchAll()` never returns a number so you must be overwriting your variable somewhere else.

Comment: I know that fetchAll() is supposed to return an array (on other pages, the exact same code returns what's expected) that's why I don't know why it print_r($result) which is placed right underneath the code section I posted returns 1.

Comment: And about the $_SESSION['user']. After a password verify I just assigned it the $_POST['user'] ($_SESSION['user']= $_POST['user'];)  I use session_start(); at the beginning of each page when I need to verify its content (if the user is the admin).

Answer (score 0):

The `fetchAll` function should be returning either an array, or a boolean FALSE.

You report that `print_r($result)` is displaying an integer value of 1.

I don't see how that's possible, unless you are assigning a different value to `$result`. Try relocating `print_r($result)` to immediately follow the assignment from `fetchAll`.

(My suspicion is that `$result` is being assigned a value of 1 elsewhere in your code, before you do the `print_r`. If there were "Issues with php connection to MySQL database", we'd be expecting to see a PDO error of some sort.)

---

NOTE: I don't think `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` is a defined fetch style for the `fetchAll` function. (`fetchAll` has different fetch styles than `fetch`.)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else stumbles upon this, between the $result variable and the print_r($result) I had an include_once(); statement (which was wrongly put there in the first place).

Thank you everyone for your answers.